# Does an Open Source implementation of "Message Bus" pattern exist for Delphi?

Tags: delphi, message-queue, enterprise, ssis

I'm looking for an implementation of this Enterprise Integration Pattern

**http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978583.aspx**

explained in a more general way on

**http://www.eaipatterns.com/Messaging.html**

Does an Open Source implementation of "Message Bus" (or message queue) pattern exist for Delphi?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a specific use of the publish/subscribe pattern.  I believe an open sourced version is available [here](http://www.mikejustin.com/habari.html) which implements a message queue.  If you search for the publish subscribe pattern, you might get more hits that reach more of what your looking for.

Comment: Thanks skamradt but I already know the "Habari ActiveMQ Client" and it is a Delphi client for ApacheMQ, not a Delphi implementation, of Message Bus pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The [Enterprise Edition of Components4Developers kbmMW](http://www.components4programmers.com/products/kbmmw/featurematrix/messagingfeatures.htm) includes messaging features (Wide Information Bus support, subject based publish/subscribe support, Synchrone and asynchrone Request/Response support, Support for selective relay and gatewaying messages, Transactional message queues ...). It is not open source however.

A video presentation is [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39181).